# android - how to get value from web-view URL ID into string

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i would like to know how to get value of the webview URL ID into string

for example we are getting web view from following url

```
   browser.loadUrl("http://www.domain.com/getrecord.php?userid=1121");
```

my question is how to get USERID which is 1121 into string onPageFinished

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// After getting URL from Web-View as 'myUrl'...Try this

// Get the Query part
String str = myUrl.getQuery();

// Get everything after '='
requiredStr = str.substring(str.indexOf('='));
```